# Tkinter GUI calculator entry values

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have built a basic calculator using Python. But then, I tried to make a real GUI calculator with Tkinter. The problem is that I don't know how to get the values and how to return the specific operation.

Basically my app is like this:

- 3 entries (first value, second value, result)
- 4 buttons (add, subtract, multiply, divide).

What I want my program to do is this: when someone enters a value in the first entry and another value in the second entry, and clicks for example on "Subtract" in the third entry the result of subtracting those numbers would be displayed. I am new to python and what I found seems too complicated.

```
from tkinter import *


def my_increase(a, b):
    return a + b


def my_decrease(a, b):
    return a - b


def my_multiply(a, b):
    return a * b


def my_divide(a, b):
    return a / b


main = Tk()

label_1 = Label(main, text="Calculator", height=5, width=30)
label_1.config(font=("OpenSans", 15))
label_1.pack()
frame_0 = Frame(main)
frame_0.pack()
frame_1 = Frame(main)
frame_1.pack()
frame_2 = Frame(main)
frame_2.pack()

button_1 = Button(frame_1, text="Add", fg="blue", command=my_increase)
button_1.config(font=("Lato", 12))
button_1.pack(side=LEFT)
button_2 = Button(frame_1, text="Subtract", fg="blue", command=my_decrease)
button_2.config(font=("Lato", 12))
button_2.pack(side=RIGHT)
button_3 = Button(frame_2, text="Multiply", fg="blue", command=my_multiply)
button_3.config(font=("Lato", 12))
button_3.pack(side=LEFT)
button_4 = Button(frame_2, text="Divide", fg="blue", command=my_divide)
button_4.config(font=("Lato", 12))
button_4.pack(side=RIGHT)
entry_1 = Entry(frame_0, bd=5)
entry_1.pack(side=TOP)
entry_2 = Entry(frame_0, bd=5)
entry_2.pack(side=TOP)
entry_3 = Entry(frame_0, bd=5)
entry_3.pack(side=TOP)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are many questions and answers related to getting values out of entry widgets, and the methods themselves are well documented. Have you done any research to try and solve this problem yourself before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function attached to each button should not require any parameters. In your example you have defined my_increase function with two parameters namely a and b. But by clicking a button no parameters are passed to function. Instead you can access the values from text boxes and add them for example.

To access values from text box you can use

```
entry_1.get()
```

To set value in text box you can use

```
entry_3.insert(0, "test")
```

Here is your code which does all the required operations like addition,subtraction,. etc

```
from Tkinter import *


def my_increase():
    entry_3.delete(0, END)
    entry_3.insert(0, int(entry_1.get()) + int(entry_2.get()))


def my_decrease():
    entry_3.delete(0, END)
    entry_3.insert(0, int(entry_1.get()) - int(entry_2.get()))


def my_multiply():
    entry_3.delete(0, END)
    entry_3.insert(0, int(entry_1.get()) * int(entry_2.get()))


def my_divide():
    entry_3.delete(0, END)
    entry_3.insert(0, int(entry_1.get()) / int(entry_2.get()))


main = Tk()

label_1 = Label(main, text="Calculator", height=5, width=30)
label_1.config(font=("OpenSans", 15))
label_1.pack()
frame_0 = Frame(main)
frame_0.pack()
frame_1 = Frame(main)
frame_1.pack()
frame_2 = Frame(main)
frame_2.pack()

button_1 = Button(frame_1, text="Add", fg="blue", command=my_increase)
button_1.config(font=("Lato", 12))
button_1.pack(side=LEFT)
button_2 = Button(frame_1, text="Subtract", fg="blue", command=my_decrease)
button_2.config(font=("Lato", 12))
button_2.pack(side=RIGHT)
button_3 = Button(frame_2, text="Multiply", fg="blue", command=my_multiply)
button_3.config(font=("Lato", 12))
button_3.pack(side=LEFT)
button_4 = Button(frame_2, text="Divide", fg="blue", command=my_divide)
button_4.config(font=("Lato", 12))
button_4.pack(side=RIGHT)
entry_1 = Entry(frame_0, bd=5)
entry_1.pack(side=TOP)
entry_2 = Entry(frame_0, bd=5)
entry_2.pack(side=TOP)
entry_3 = Entry(frame_0, bd=5)
entry_3.pack(side=TOP)
main.mainloop()
```